# Response.Cookies["MyCookie"].Value warns of null reference exception

Tags: asp.net, cookies, resharper, nullreferenceexception

I use ReSharper for VisualStudio and was wondering why a Response would warrant a null reference exception warning for the following **bold** text:

**HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies["MyCookie"]**.Value = "MyValue";

I've always known this to be the way to initialize a new cookie, and would only expect this warning to be generated for *Requesting* a cookie value. Is ReSharper lying to me? If not, what's going on? Thanks a lot.

Comment: I personally have only Used the `.Add`, like [shown on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcookie.aspx).

Comment: Thank Brad. To error on the side of caution, I actually modified my code to correspond to that MSDN article. It's a bit cleaner than how I was originally doing it, although after some research, I do think my original code was fine - ReSharper was just confused.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Resharper just isn't smart enough to know that behind the scenes this collection will lazily create objects for you.

**Request**.Cookies will return null if the cookie doesn't exist... but **Response**.Cookie will create them for you if they didn't exist.

Comment: Thanks for that, you're right: "For the first cookie, the values of the Cookies collection are set directly. You can add values to the collection this way because Cookies derives from a specialized collection of type NameObjectCollectionBase.